# Show that the map $\phi$ is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set.

I want to show that the map $\phi:\{0,1\}^X\rightarrow 2^X$, $f\mapsto \{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$ is a bijection.

$$$$

So we have to show that the map is injective and surjective.

For the injectivity:

Let $f_1, f_2\in \{0,1\}^X$ with $f_1\neq f_2$.

If the valus of a function is equal to $1$, then the other function cannot be equal to $1$ for the same $x$.

Does this mean then that $\{x\in X\mid f_1(x)=1\}\neq \{x\in X\mid f_2(x)=1\}$ ?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of $2^X$? Because to me, $2$ is _exactly the same_ as $\{0,1\}$, making this result trivial.

Comment: The commenter Arthur makes a very good point on proper syntax; the natural and elegant notation to be used here is $\mathscr{P}(A)$ for the set of all **p**arts (subsets) of $A$.

Comment: @Arthur The OP once used $2^X$ for the power set of $X$. I think they keep using the same notation.

Comment: May I point out that in many instances of mathematics rather than arguing separately for the injectivity and the surjectivity of a certain map exhibiting its inverse -- when it can be expressed naturally and effortlessly -- sheds far more light in understanding the structures at hand. This consideration specifically applies to this instance.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_1 \neq f_2$, where $f_1,f_2: X \to \{0,1\}$, this means by the definition of equality of functions that there is some $x_0 \in X$ such that $f_1(x_0) \neq f_2(x_0)$ and because the codomain is $\{0,1\}$ this means that one of these is $0$ and the other $1$, say $f_0(x_0)=0$ and $f_1(x_0)=1$ for definiteness.

But then, by definition, $x_0 \notin \phi(f_0)=\{x \in X: f_0(x)=1\}$ while $x_0 \in \phi(f_1)=\{x \in X: f_1(x)=1\}$ so the sets $\phi(f_0)$ and $\phi(f_1)$ are distinct. So $\phi: \{0,1\}^X \to \mathscr{P}(X)$ is an injection, as it sends different functions to different sets.

To see surjectivity, let $A \in \mathscr{P}(X)$. Define

$$\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \notin A\\
                           1 & x \in A
              \end{cases}
$$

and note that $\chi_A \in \{0,1\}^X$ and $\phi(\chi_A)=A$ by definition.

Comment: $f\in \{0,1\}^X$ means that $f:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$, right? The proof for injectivity is clear!! Thank you!! Now it is left to show also the surjectivity. We have to show that: For each $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$ there is a $f$ such that $\phi (f)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$. When we consider a set $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$ we have already the function $f$, by definition of the set, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, $\{0,1\}^X=\{f: X \to \{0,1\}\}$ as a shorthand. And make the map explicit for surjectivity as I did in the edit.

Comment: About surjectivity: For each set we define the characteristic function and so , by definition of surjectivity, for each $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$ the function $f$ is the characteristic function?

Comment: @MaryStar You have to find a pre-image for each subset so you have to *define* a function $f$ with $\phi(f)$ equal to that set. That $f$ will be the charcateristic function, you have no choice, as the pre-image is unique (as we have an injective map).

Answer (score 0):

Let us rephrase your problem a bit. Consider an arbitrary set $A$ (can very well be empty and there is absolutely no reason to disregard this particular case, as trivial as it may be; the general result is also valid for it as well) and the following objects:

- for each $X \subseteq A$ define **the characteristic function of** $X$ by 
  $$\chi_X: A \to \{0,1\}\\ \chi_X(x)= 
  \begin{cases} 1, x \in X \\ 0, x \notin X \end{cases}$$
- for any arbitrary sets $M, N$ write $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ens}}(M, N)$ for **the set of all maps** from $M$ to $N$
- define the maps:
  $$\Phi: \mathscr{P}(A) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ens}}(A, \{0,1\})\\
  \Phi(X)=\chi_X$$
  together with
  $$\Psi: \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ens}}(A, \{0,1\}) \to \mathscr{P}(A)\\
  \Psi(f)=f^{-1}(\{1\})$$

It should be an easy exercise to prove that $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are mutual inverses. Take a look at this presentation and see if it clarifies your question.